# Cassandra large python queries

Tags: python, numpy, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I'm using python driver to get some time series data. I wanna have the data in a numpy array.

So the problem is transforming the pagedResult I get into a numpy array.
Currently I just do `for row in result: out.append(row.price)`. This is very very slow, because of the pagination. I tried using `statement = SimpleStatement(select_query, fetch_size=10**6)` but I get

````
cassandra.ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'data_retrieved': False, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 1}```
````

How do I read fast about 10^7 rows and get them into numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in multiple partitions, you should query the different partitions asynchronously.

If you know some bounds, you can query multiple slices of the partition at once from different replicas.

See the following page in the documentation for recommendations on getting the most performance out of the python driver by using asynchronous queries in parallel:

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/docs/performance.rst